# Can I remove a parameter from the Dapper DynamicParameters?

Tags: c#, json, dapper

I am retrieving data from a external source. My class matches the response of the JSON. However there is an inner object inside the json. How can I remove it when I am passing it to the dynamic parameters in Dapper?

Basic structure of the class

```
{
   "name": "John",
   ... 30 more fields here ...

   "location": {
       "city": "abcd", 
       "zip": "87123"
    }
}
```

Using this like:

```
foreach (var result in response.results) 
{
    var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
    parameters.AddDynamicParams(result);

    // I need to remove "location" from this parameter
    // and then I can add the city and zip

    parameters.AddDynamicParams(result.location.city); // etc

    db.Execute("save_data", parameters, commandType:CommandType.StoredProcedure);
}
```

Comment: Looks like you need check that result has childs elements, if use you need add to  parameters only child items.Maybe you need recursion method.

Comment: You can use any text editor with decent search-replace facilities to write out the 33 properties you need. The alternative is creating something that trivially breaks by someone adding a new property or rearranging the structure of the existing data. The use of `DynamicParameters` here is questionable -- `save_data` does not have a dynamic list of parameters, it only has those it's declared with. If you do want the ability to fully dynamically process data, it would make more sense to pass the JSON directly to the stored procedure and parse it in `save_data` (if you have SQL Server 2016+).

Comment: There's also AutoMapper for converting between classes that are almost, but not completely identical (like whatever `result` would be and the class that represents the parameters of `save_data`).

Comment: @jeroen - 
1. Using SQL 2008R2
2. The ASP.NET code is more generic than the above, where its processing multiple kind of Json. The "special parameters" can be assigned to the sub class to process.

Answer (score 1):

Still waiting for an answer, but here is the workaround I have started using

```
foreach (var result in response.results) {
  var parameters = new DynamicParameters();

  foreach (PropertyInfo prop in result.GetType().GetProperties()) {
      
      if (!SpecialParameter(result, prop, parameters))
         parameters.Add(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(result, null));

  }

  db.Execute("save_data",
         parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
}    


function SpecialParameter(result, prop, parameters) {
// can be implemented in the sub class

   switch (prop.Name) {
      case "location":
         parameters.Add("location_city", result.city);
         parameters.Add("location_state", result.state);
         return true;
   }

  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to be able to send Dapper strong types rather than anonymous objects, example:

```
var myObject = new MyClass{
  MyProperty = 1
};

_connection.ExecuteAsync(
  "InsertStoredProcedure",
  myObject,
  commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure
)
```

That works just fine, but let's say `MyClass` has an `Id` int that gets auto-incremented in the database. I don't need to pass it in as an argument, and I don't want to have to update my stored procedure to take a dummy id argument that won't get used.

Fortunately Dapper's DynamicParameters constructor knows what to do if you give it a dictionary version of your object, so using reflection you can convert it to a dictionary, remove any fields you don't want, and then create a set of DynamicParameters from that.

Now the question is how to do that generically. If you have a lot of different entities that you want to use with Dapper, you don't want to have to convert them to dictionaries and remove the fields you don't want each time. You can solve that by making an attribute.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class DapperIgnore : Attribute {}
```

Then decorate your class with the field(s) you want to ignore.

```
 public class MyClass {

   [DapperIgnore]
   public long Id {get; set;}

   public int MyProperty {get; set;}
 }
```

Now you can create an extension method that wraps the Dapper version.

```
public static async Task<int> ExecuteWithTypeAsync<TInput>(
  this IDbConnection cnn,
  string sql,
  TInput input,
  IDbTransaction transaction = null,
  int? commandTimeout commandTimeout = null,
  CommandType? commandType = null
){
   var dictionary = typeof(TInput).GetProperties()
     .Where(property => property
         .GetCustomAttributes(false)
         .All(attr => attr is not DapperIgnore)
     )
     .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.GetValue(input));

     var parameters = new DynamicParameters(dictionary);
     return await cnn.ExecuteAsync(sql, parameters, transaction, commandTimeout, commandType);
}
```

Note that you should name the method differently than the Dapper method it wraps--even though you've added a type argument--otherwise this will become the new method that is used everywhere, even with anonymous objects.

Now you can do

```
_connection.ExecuteWithTypeAsync(
  "InsertStoredProcedure",
  myObject,
  commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure
)
```

...and it will not include the `Id` property that you decorated with the [DapperIgnore] attribute.